# number of options to divide $n$ white balls into $r$ cells

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve the following question:
number of options to divide $n$ white balls into $r$ cells.

or, more specifically:
what is the number of options to divide 4 white balls into 3 cells?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that there can be empty cells, in which case this problem can be solved using [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

If there are $n$ white balls and $r$ cells, we can think of this as arranging $r-1$ dividers among $n$ objects. Equivalently, we are choosing the places of $r-1$ objects in a line of length $n+r-1$. This is a [combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination):

$$\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}=\binom{n+r-1}{n}$$

---

In your example with $4$ white balls and $3$ cells, we have $2$ dividers and $6$ total objects, so the number of ways to place the balls in the cells is $$\binom{6}{2}= \frac{6 \cdot 5}{2}=\boxed{15}$$

Comment: I see. thank you! the link is also very helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method.  What you do is you lay out the four white balls, then you place two bars somewhere in between each ball to create *three* partitions:

\begin{align}
|&& ||****&&| \\
|&&|*|***&&| \\
|&&|**|**&&| \\
|&&|***|*&&| \\
|&& |****|&& |\\
|&& *||***&& |\\
|&&*|*|** && |\\
|&&*|**|* && |\\
|&&*|***| && |\\
|&& **||** && |\\
|&&**|*|* && |\\
|&& **|**|&& |\\
|&&***||* && |\\
|&&***|*| && |\\
|&&****|| && |\\
\end{align}

In the first five, the first partition holds *zero* balls.  There are two bars plus four stars.  This means there are $2 + 4 = 6$ total positions (in the middle--I only drew the two bars on the outside to show the partitions).  All we need to do is choose the $4$ places for the $4$ stars *or* choose the $2$ places for the *two* bars: [$\binom{6}{2}$](https://www.google.com/search?q=6+choose+2)$=$[$\binom{6}{4}$](https://www.google.com/search?q=6+choose+4)$=15$.

In general, if you have $n$ balls (stars) and $r$ cells (thus $r - 1$ bars--think about that), then there are$\binom{n + r - 1}{n} = \binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1}$ ways to fill those $r$ partitions.

Comment: ok, understood. Thank you for your detailed explanation!!